# Netty (4.0.4) version compress/decompress string messages error

Tags: java, gzip, netty

I want to apply compress/decompress on Netty client/server I use the following code for pipeline in both client and sever:

```
@Override
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(
    8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));

pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
pipeline.addLast("gzipdeflater", ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibEncoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));
pipeline.addLast("gzipinflater", ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibDecoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));

// and then business logic.
pipeline.addLast("handler", new NettyClientHandler());        
}
```

and the server as:

```
@Override
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(
    8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
pipeline.addLast("gzipdeflater", ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibEncoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));
pipeline.addLast("gzipinflater", ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibDecoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));
//GlibDecoder
//pipeline.addLast("decoder", new ZlibDecoder());
//pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
// and then business logic.
pipeline.addLast("handler", new NettyServerHandler());        
}
```

and I got the following error in the client on starting the connection

> > WARNING: Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0x3553bb5c] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jzlib/Inflater    at
> >     io.netty.handler.codec.compression.JZlibDecoder.(JZlibDecoder.java:28)
> >       at
> >     io.netty.handler.codec.compression.ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibDecoder(ZlibCodecFactory.java:86)
> >       at
> >     testChat.NettyClientInitializer.initChannel(NettyClientInitializer.java:36)
> >       at
> >     testChat.NettyClientInitializer.initChannel(NettyClientInitializer.java:21)
> >       at
> >     io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.channelRegistered(ChannelInitializer.java:70)
> >       at
> >     io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRegistered(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:188)
> >       at
> >     io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRegistered(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:174)
> >       at
> >     io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRegistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:730)
> >       at
> >     io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:426)
> >       at
> >     io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$100(AbstractChannel.java:367)
> >       at
> >     io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:403)
> >       at
> >     io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:353)
> >       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:366)     at
> >     io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
> >       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
> >     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jzlib.Inflater   at
> >     java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
> >     java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
> >     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> >     java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)     at
> >     sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)     ... 15 more

Exception in thread "main" java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

the client/server work fine without compress stuff I try to put the compression/decompression before string encoding but I got the same error? any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Comments after many trials I found the correct solution for my Question as:
- in netbeans I added jzlib-1.1.2.jar to my project.
- the correct order for the pipline as the following code:

```
pipeline.addLast("deflater", ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibEncoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));
pipeline.addLast("inflater", ZlibCodecFactory.newZlibDecoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));

pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(
        8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));


pipeline.addLast("decoder", new MyStringDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new MyStringEncoder());
```

in both Client and Server

Comment: Isn't the ZlibEncoder is the inflater and the ZlibDecoder is the deflater? Because in this case you are still mixed up?

Comment: I follow the example [link](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/factorial/FactorialClientInitializer.html) it shows deflater with ZlibEncoder and inflater with ZlibDecoder check by your self.

Comment: To clarify, inflate is the operation that decompresses the data, by inflating it to its original size, as such, it is the decoder, which decodes the previously deflated content.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the following dependency in your pom.xml:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jzlib</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

This is because netty declare all dependencies as optional.

Comment: I'm using netbeans, is that file equal to project.xml or build.xml

Comment: since I don't use maven configuration I add netty jar files to my project and I compile.

Comment: ok I added jzlib-1.1.2.jar to my project and I got no error in connection but frankly no zipping action happened I think there is some issues in the order of gzipdeflater/gzipinflater do you have any idea?